# Need help in generating Query

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I have a doubt in generating Query.

Which is best way in these two

Eg:1

```
DECLARE @SQLQuery varchar(MAX)
SET @SQLQuery='Select tab1.Name,tab2.Name From table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.ID=table1.ID'

IF @Val=0
 SET @SQLQuery=@SQLQuery+' where table1.ID>5'
ELSE
 SET @SQLQuery=@SQLQuery+' where table2.ID>5'
```

Eg 2:

```
IF @Val=0
BEGIN
Select tab1.Name,tab2.Name 
From table1 
INNER JOIN table2 
    ON table2.ID=table1.ID
WHERE table1.ID>5
END
ELSE
BEGIN
Select tab1.Name,tab2.Name 
From table1 
INNER JOIN table2 
    ON table2.ID=table1.ID
WHERE table2.ID>5
END
```

Comment: What are your criteria for evaluating "best"?

Comment: using variable and the executing the Query or Direct method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Select tab1.Name,tab2.Name 
From table1 
INNER JOIN table2 
    ON table2.ID=table1.ID
WHERE (@Val=0 AND table1.ID>5) OR (@Val!=0 AND table2.ID>5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IF @Val = 0
BEGIN
    Select T1.Name From
    (
        Select Name From table1 Where Id > 5
    )T1
    INNER JOIN table2 T2 ON T2.ID = T1.ID

END
ELSE
BEGIN
    Select T2.Name From
    (
        Select Name From table2 Where Id > 5
    )T2
    INNER JOIN table1 T1 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
END
```

In this way, We should first filter the values and then join between them.

Comment: The optimizer should be smart enough to work out in what order to apply criteria from the WHERE clause - trying to "force" an evaluation order, as you're trying above, may not work, and/or may tie the optimizers hands from doing the best possible job (e.g. if there are 95% of rows in Table2 with an ID > 5, but only 6 rows in total in table1, and these only match 5% of rows in Table2, you'd want it to apply the join first (and it probably still will))

Comment: I thought, the joins execute sequentially. When you said "The optimizer should be smart enough to work out in what order to apply criteria from the WHERE clause - trying to "force" an evaluation order". Thanks for this. Can you share the link? I will like to check more on this.